# Converting hexadecimal colour string back to integer

Tags: java, android, parsing, integer, hex

Earlier I got the integer value for a colour and converted it to Hexadecimal for storing in a database, now when i read it back and try to convert it back to an integer to use `.setBackgroundColor(int)` i get the following error

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "ff0071dc"

on this line

```
items[i].setColourCode(Integer.parseInt(currentJourneys.get(i).getJourneyColourCode(), 16));
```

Also, if I hardcode in the hex value like this
`colourLbl.setBackgroundColor(0xff0071dc);` it works fine

Am I doing something wrong? How else can i get the hex value out and use it to set the background colour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities to convert a `hex` representation to int.

By casting a parsed long to int

```
int color = (int) Long.parseLong(hex, 16);
```

or by using a `BigInteger` to parse the value

```
int color = new BigInteger(hex, 16).intValue();
```

---

Some time in the future you might also be able to use the Java 8 method for parsing unsigned int values

```
int color = Integer.parseUnsignedInt(hex, 16);
```

Comment: Summed up: parseInt breaks on an integer value that is unsigned above the signed Integer.MAX:VALUE. Nice mentioning parseUnsignedInt that solves this long-standing issue.

Answer (score 2):

I will recommend `Color.parseString()` to do it.

> Parse the color string, and return the corresponding color-int. If the string cannot be parsed, throws an IllegalArgumentException exception. Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names: 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuchsia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple', 'silver', 'teal'.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String)